# how to add additioanla parameter in referral URL in Magento

Tags: magento, redirect, compare

I want to add additional parameter in referral URL. in Magento when I add item to compare list, it successfully added and then it redirect to referral URL. while going back to referral URL i want to add some additional parameters in the URL.

$this->_redirectReferer(); if i call the function it redirects the previous page. for example it redirects to http://magento.com/product.html

instead of this i want to redirect to http://magento.com/product.phtml/?timestamp

basically i want to add some additional parameter in my referral URL.